# code in parent window crashes after destroying child window to continue after validation, how to proceed?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

My idea is to open a parent window that treats data in a DB, to do this treatment I first need to validate the login and password (I open a child window, type username and password, do the validation and destroy the window after validation), then of the destroyed window I need to sequence the code and do the treatment, but the code hangs as if the child window had not been destroyed, and only continues when I close the parent window. dry the example code.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time


class login:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('WINDOWN CHILD')

        self.user = None
        self.passw = None

        #Make Window 10X10

        rows = 0
        while rows < 11:
            self.root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            self.root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            rows += 1

        self.root.geometry('255x225+700+300')

        #Username and Password

        frame = LabelFrame(self.root, text='User Authentication')

        frame.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=11, rowspan=11)

        Label(frame, text=' Usename ').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.username = Entry(frame)
        self.username.grid(row=2, column=2)

        Label(frame, text=' Password ').grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.password = Entry(frame, show='*')
        self.password.grid(row=5, column=2)

        # Button

        ttk.Button(frame, text='LOGIN', command=self.login_user).grid(row=7, column=2)

        #Message Display
        self.message = tkinter.Label(self.root, text='', fg='Red')
        self.message.grid(row=9, column=6)

    def login_user(self):
        self.message['fg'] = 'Blue'
        self.message['text'] = 'saved password'
        self.root.update()

        self.user = self.username.get()
        self.passw = self.password.get()

        time.sleep(1)
        self.root.destroy()


class parent:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.user_name = None
        self.password = None
        self.window_child = None
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('PARENT')

        ttk.Button(self.root, text='PRINCIPAL', command=self.test).grid(row=7, column=2)

    def test(self):
        child = Toplevel()
        self.window_child = login(child)
        child.mainloop()

        #when the child window is destroyed
        self.user_name = self.window_child.user
        self.password = self.window_child.passw
        print(self.user_name, '----', self.password)
        
        #and do a lot more things


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    application = parent(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't call `.mainloop()` more than once. Use `child.wait_window()` instead of `child.mainloop()` inside `test()`.

Comment: very good, worked perfectly!

thank you so much @acw1668

would you have a problem before destroying the child window (in `def login_user()` of the `class login`) adding the line `self.root.quit()`?

I did this and it worked the same way